# Seismic sensors?

Tags: sensor, vibration

I notice that there seem to be relatively few seismic intrusion detection systems available as pre-packaged products, so I am wondering about the feasibility of hacking one up.

Is it as simple as buying a set of "seismic sensors" (whatever that is) and connecting them via coax to something, a seismic receiver (does that exist?) or is it more complicated than that. What are the parameters of a working design?

Comment: Do you have a data sheet for one that is not pre-packaged?

Comment: here is a simple vibration sensor  ... https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/workshop/diy/vibration-sensor-forrest-mims.html

Comment: [Here is the datasheet of a commercial solution from BOSCH](http://resource.boschsecurity.com/documents/Data_sheet_enUS_2638245003.pdf)

Comment: I guess you opened up a bounty on this. But I have no idea if you are talking about home security or bank vault security or what. Frankly, I've had so MUCH trouble getting vibrations OUT of optical systems I've worked on, that I'd have to say that every single one of them starts out as a good detector system. The direction I'd head in this would be based on the astigmatic quad detector used on CD/DVD drives which are now extremely cheap but highly repeatable designs. In short, I'd look towards optical methods. Very sensitive and rather cheap these days. Write more, though.

Comment: I guess you could use a mass spring damper system and some sort of interferometric measurement system.

Comment: And yeah. Google confirms, Fabry Perot interferometer based seismometers have been done... Of course. If I could imagine one in the matter of a SE-comment, then for sure it was thought out by researchers.

Comment: A commercial geophone might be a good start: here's one supplier <http://www.bgmicro.com/search.aspx?find=geophone> but this is only the sensor.

Comment: @jonk Vibration sensors on bank vaults etc are called "vibration detectors". Seismic intrusion detection specifically refers to situations where a human (or vehicle) is entering an outdoor protected area (or a large indoor area like a warehouse) and their footfalls are being detected.

Comment: @TylerDurden Thanks for the clarification. I'm not involved in this area and the terms are vague to me. Clarification of terminology appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sesmic sensors are probably going to be cost prohibitive since they are built to detect very low frequency waves. Although there are [some accelerometers](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/D7S-A0001/Z5835CT-ND/6133945) that are inexpensive that might work.

An easier and cheaper way to do this would be to use acoustic sensors and triangulate the position of entry's at a location. You could possibly calibrate the system and then detect when sound or excessive sound is coming from a particular location. You could probably get a good idea of when people are opening and closing doors or even windows or even moving through a location, although this would take some smart algorithms that discriminate on location.

[image]
Source: [NDE](https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Other%20Methods/AE/AE_Source%20Location.php)

Answer (score 2):

The main issues are: you would need very sensitive measurements, you would need to synchronize the data in some way to get location information, and you'd need to tune the system for different areas. All of this really needs to be done to differentiate between an intruder and the building setting or wind or temperature changes, and even then the system would not work in many solidly built places. [This Bosch sensor](http://resource.boschsecurity.com/documents/Data_sheet_enUS_2638245003.pdf), which was linked earlier, is targeted to detect opening vault doors and such, and in that limited situation it probably works fine.

I work with vibrations pretty much every day. Every time you step on the ground, you put the same amount of energy into the ground, but the vibrations you generate are different based on the hardness of the contact (I'm electrical not mechanical, so I may be using the wrong terms). Tap shoes onto a hardwood floor will make a fast, high acceleration. Slippers onto a carpet will make a low amplitude shock spread over a wider time.

The way these waves propagate will be different based on what they're propagating through. Walls, furniture, and beams will interfere with the propagation and cause reflections or absorption. So, you might get a solution working fine in one situation, but failing when the source is on the other side of an invisible support beam.

Here is a worst case situation of me in my winter boots jumping next to a 16g accelerometer. The floor is cheap hardwood overlay over (I think) concrete.
[image: Vibrations through solid floor. There are none]
Pretty hard to see any vibrations, and I was right next to the unit.

On the other hand, here is the same unit on a pretty flimsy table, with me tapping the table with my fist:
[image: Vibrations on a shaky table]
Lots of shaking.

If you can measure the vibrations and figure out the reflections through the area, if you want to localize the source of the vibrations, you need to synchronize your data and apply something called beamforming. The resolution you can get out of beamforming depends on the synchronization, wave propagation speed, and the number and spacing of your sensors. Waves propagate very quickly in mechanical systems.

Like I said earlier, in some situations vibration sensing for security may work, but it needs to be tuned carefully. [Here's a neat related blog on analyzing footbridge traffic with some accelerometers](https://blog.mide.com/university-drive-pedestrian-bridge-resonance).

Answer (score 2):

Having spent 2 summer jobs in Seismic Recording and built a dozen portable Geophone amplifier data recording devices, my tests indicate that furnace vibrations can be detected in floor vibration as well as gentle walking even on a concrete basement floor.  The lower frequency response needed to support this and seismic signals was <<1 Hz.

### <1Hz Frequency Response, quiet solid floor needed

You wont get this from a low mass sensor unless it is firmly attached to a rigid substrate.  The floors and building furnace air movers must be solid and quiet for this level of detection to work at sub-sonic frequencies.  Otherwise if the floors are soft with carpet it is also possible to escape detection.

Geophones are extremely sensitive heavy moving magnets in fixed coils with small magnetic gaps and have low frequency suspensions.  Seismic recordings are made placing it on a larger stable rock secured by earth around the edges.  We could pick up ground reflections from 30 km deep and detonations created 800 km away. You could also pick up a deer walking 100m away in the woods.

In my experiment, I placed a geophone on the basement concrete floor in the lab of the Earth Sciences building at U of M and increased the analog gain until the building vibration moved the needle. Then 2 meters away I could peg the needle just by doing a knee bend, so intrusion detection could be feasible at this range.

Piezo sensors , MEMs accelerometer and microphones can all fail due to the lack of low frequency response. but may be ok as Noise detectors but may pickup false triggers.

### RF motional sensor works better with PIR

However in later years I found using tuning a dipole at 180MHz for minimum return loss using the mV signals on a directional coupler into a Schottky diode was far more sensitive at motion sensing 10m away in the direction of max gain.

The other common method is laser beams with multiple mirrors but expensive.     Modulated IR carrier bursts with AGC are very sensitive with daylight blocking , cheap and used for Garage driveway motion sensor Lights but often picks up moving branches.

- https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.residential-wireless-rf-motion-detector.1000742603.html
- X_Band with PIR https://www.security.honeywell.com/hsc/products/intruder-detection-systems/wireless/motion-sensor/298481.html
- https://ca.dhgate.com/product/wireless-pir-sensor-motion-detector-sensor/150612777.html?utm_source=pla&utm_medium=GMC&utm_campaign=egomall&utm_term=150612777&f=bm%7c150612777%7c007002%7cGMC%7c912767178%7cpla%7cegomall%7cCA%7c007002003%7cc%7c%7c2%7c

But I was not intending to do a Consumer Test on all commercial motion sensors , only report that geophones can work with 1Hz response. They are also expensive.

Comment: Are you recommending "rf motional sensors" over geophones? If so, what would be a design/schematic for the sensor (if it cannot be bought)?

Comment: I like @Jonk 's idea of use a DVD laser gimbal mechanism as a low frequency vibration sensor, but you may need his granite slab to stabilize the ambient and act as a floor transducer.

Answer (score 1):

There exists precise analog seismic sensors or less precise MEMS motion sensors. The choice depend on the scale of energy where the detection should be done and how complex the trigger must be to avoid false positive, because in many situations a real seismic sensors will record a lot of unrelated sources at the same time.

Comment: So, to interpret your answer... are you basically saying that it would very tricky to hack up an effective system because it would involve complicated signal processing or algorithms?

Comment: Maybe. This entirely depend on the context where the intrusion detection take place and your trigger expectations. If you can grant that the noise floor is below a certain level and that triggering on a much higher level fulfill your expectation, then a simple comparator will be enough. In practice, real seismic sensors processing use normalized math operations to compute differents parameters that can be part of the trigger like pike energy, frequency of the pike, average energy at certain frequencies, duration, etc...

Comment: I agree with Jean. If you are going to install the sensor in a remote area with almost zero human presence than a normal sensor with minimun electronics is ok. However if there is a road close by or anything of this kind then you need a more precise sensor with necesary SW. For example any truck, car which passes on a road would create false data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your price range there appear to be some [commercial options](https://www.jmac.com/Honeywell_Ademco_SC105_p/HONEYWELL-ADEMCO-SC105.htm). All the low cost sensors I saw are designed to me mounted inside a safe or similar. If that's your application then you should be good. But if you're looking to bury the sensor and detect digging I didn't see any cheap off the shelf options for that.

If you want to go the DIY route, there appear to be some diy seismic sensor projects you could start from. [Example1](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Seismic-Activity-Monitor-Ethernet-Shield/), [example2](http://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/may2012_Newton), [example3](http://www.infiltec.com/seismo/)

"Hacking" something together with 2-3 parts doesn't seem feasible unfortunately. The issue is that there don't appear to be any cheap, simple to use seismic sensors available. I found a few like [this](https://smile.amazon.com/WINGONEER-Sensitive-vibration-sensor-SW-18010P/dp/B06XHGHQLB/), but they're not anywhere close to seismograph level sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

> I notice that there seem to be relatively few seismic intrusion detection systems

I used to fit these some 40 years ago.
Apart from safe mounting though they were prone to false triggering and fell out of favour.
From memory detectors were basically 2 horizontal wires with a ball bearing balanced on it.
With modern signal processing perhaps you could do something with that.

We did not use them on unmanned premises though there had to be a security presence to avoid annoying the police with the false alarms.

EDIT

If you want to detect footfalls you could try burying a hosepipe with a microphone at the end.
This explains.

[https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Erik_Vavrinsky/publication/43968431_Electronic_intruder_alarm_systems_in_object_protection/links/55a7769c08ae0b4e87121f02/Electronic-intruder-alarm-systems-in-object-protection.pdf][1]

The military experimented with similar back then.